# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 This is the code from a book website?

Tags: java

```
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac Gambler.java
 *  Execution:    java Gambler stake goal N
 *  
 *  Simulates a gambler who start with $stake and place fair $1 bets
 *  until she goes broke or reach $goal. Keeps track of the number of
 *  times she wins and the number of bets she makes. Run the experiment N
 *  times, averages the results, and prints them out.
 *
 *  % java Gambler 50 250 1000
 *  Percent of games won = 19.0
 *  Avg # bets            = 9676.302
 *
 *  % java Gambler 50 150 1000
 *  Percent of games won = 31.9
 *  Avg # bets            = 4912.13
 *
 *  % java Gambler 50 100 1000
 *  Percent of games won = 49.6
 *  Avg # bets            = 2652.352
 *
 *************************************************************************/

public class Gambler { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int stake = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);    // gambler's stating bankroll
        int goal  = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);    // gambler's desired bankroll
        int T     = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);    // number of trials to perform

        int bets = 0;        // total number of bets made
        int wins = 0;        // total number of games won

        // repeat N times
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {

            // do one gambler's ruin simulation
            int cash = stake;
            while (cash > 0 && cash < goal) {
                bets++;
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) cash++;     // win $1
                else                     cash--;     // lose $1
            }
            if (cash == goal) wins++;                // did gambler go achieve desired goal?
        }

        // print results
        System.out.println(wins + " wins of " + T);
        System.out.println("Percent of games won = " + 100.0 * wins / T);
        System.out.println("Avg # bets           = " + 1.0 * bets / T);
    }

}
```

I try this code from and I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you give inputs when running the program? This is explicitely stated in the class' comment! _"java Gambler 50 250 1000"_

Comment: Please use the edit link below your question and fix the code formatting.

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: As you are new user here, let me tell you if you find the solution of your problem here in any answer, you should then accept that answer to let other users know what worked for you. To accept an answer just click on the Right Tick sign on the left side of answer whichever you want to accept.

Comment: +point for you can ask next question

Answer (score 4):

This program accepts **[Command Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)** that are stored in the form of an array and you need to pass them *while executing* the program.

And as seen from the code there should be **three** arguments. If you don't pass them, you will be getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You need to run your program like,

`java Gambler 10 20 30`

Here `10, 20 and 30` are the three Command Line arguments and will be passed to `String[] args` which are then used in your main method.

If you try to run your program by `java Gambler` You will definitely get the exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`, which you are getting.

As per @ZouZou 's comment:

To pass Command Line Arguments from Eclipse:

`Run -> Run Configurations -> Argument tabs -> Program arguments and you fill it there.`

Comment: just curious, and i think also useful for future readers... , how would OP achieve this when running it from eclipse? (adding the arguments)

Comment: @BartHofma Run -> Run Configurations -> Argument tabs -> Program arguments and you fill it there.

Comment: thanks.. maybe @GPRathour can add it to his answer?, got my vote anyway, but for a complete answer :)

Comment: @BartHofma Did it. Thanks for your suggestion and raising this Good Point. :)